# SD card won't mount for no reason

Tags: 16.04, command-line, mount, sd-card

I'm trying to mount my SD card to `/media/SD` using the terminal command `sudo mount`, but this happens:

```
$ sudo mount -t vfat /dev/mmcblk1 /media/SD
mount: /dev/mmcblk1 is already mounted or /media/SD busy
```

I delete and replace `/media/SD` and it still doesn't work

```
$ sudo rm -r /media/SD
$ sudo mkdir /media/SD
$ sudo mount -t vfat /dev/mmcblk1 /media/SD
mount: /dev/mmcblk1 is already mounted or /media/SD busy
```

the SD card is not mounted

```
$ sudo umount /dev/mmcblk1
umount: /dev/mmcblk1: not mounted
```

the SD card is stored as /dev/mmcblk1

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/mmcblk1: 59.5 GiB, 63864569856 bytes, 124735488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

also the `kill` command does work either

Comment: My SD cards mount automatically.

Comment: Please post the output of the commands `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo lsblk -m`, when the SD card is connected. Edit the original question and indent each line (of the output) 4 spaces to render it as 'code'.

Comment: @sudodus I did the command `sudo fdisk -l` and added the output to my question `fdisk` can be used to edit SD do you know how I can use it

Comment: 1. Please post the whole output of the commands sudo lsblk -f and sudo lsblk -m, when the SD card is connected; 2. Also, please post the whole output of the command `cat /etc/mtab` -- For all this output, please edit the original question and indent each line (of the output) 4 spaces to render it as 'code'. -- Depending on the output we can try different methods to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a partition table on the SD card, so if in the unusual case that you put a filesystem on the unpartitioned device, you need the loop option, -oloop in the mount command.  If you have nothing on the card and you want to use it normally, add a partition to it with fdisk, then make a filesystem on it with mkfs.vfat.  If you actually have data on the card, you should not make a new filessytem on it, but try a recovery tool like testdisk.
  Learning to use a new tool, start with the "man" pages,(manual),

```
man fdisk
```

Answer (score -1):

Insert another usb stick beside the sd card  at the same time

Then type lsusb and see if it still exist

If you have a gui:
 try formatting the usb stick  through    the file manager
 a window will aber
select your sdcard and mount it

Comment: did nothing ....

Comment: do your os have a gui?

Comment: what do you mean by 'did nothing'? Were you able to mount it? Or did you have the same issue?